# Creating a Stored Procedure with if statement on Inner Join

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, join

I am trying to create a stored procedure which would execute an `INNER JOIN` code block based on a parameter value. However, I keep getting "Incorrect syntax near '@reSourceID'."

```
if (@VendorID = 11)
    @reSourceID = 't.reSourceID'
if (@VendorID = 5)
    @reSourceID = 't.SourceID'

SELECT      t.ID, fsg.SigCap, fsg.VendorId
FROM        FormCap fsg
    INNER JOIN FlightTrip t
        ON fsg.SourceId = @reSourceID
        AND fsg.VendorId = @VendorID
    INNER JOIN ContractProvider cpu 
        ON t.Id = cpu.VendorId 
WHERE       (t.ID = @FinTransID)
AND     (cpu.userID = @UserID)
```

Any ideas what would be causing the error?

Comment: You cannot use variables for table and column names in your T-SQL statements. They won't be recognized - you'll need to resort to *dynamic SQL* if you really must do this

Comment: Your join doesn't make sense: The join condition for FlightCap depends only on columns in FormCap, which means every row of FlightTrip will be joined if the FormCap row matches.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT      t.ID, fsg.SigCap, fsg.VendorId
FROM        FormCap fsg
    INNER JOIN FlightTrip t
        ON fsg.SourceId = CASE @VendorID
                              WHEN 11 THEN t.reSourceID
                              WHEN  5 THEN t.SourceID
                          END
        AND fsg.VendorId = @VendorID
    INNER JOIN ContractProvider cpu 
        ON t.Id = cpu.VendorId 
WHERE       (t.ID = @FinTransID)
AND     (cpu.userID = @UserID)
```

Comment: The case statement helped eliminate the need for the If statement, which was causing the error. Thanks Anon.

Answer (score 4):

Your syntax error is because you haven't really joined on FlightTrip t.  You can't do what you are trying to do in compiled SQL.  You would have to create a varchar variable full of your statement and then use EXEC SP_EXECUTESQL(@Statement) to run it.

```
declare @statement nvarchar(4000)

select @statement = '
           SELECT      t.ID, 
                       fsg.SigCap, 
                       fsg.VendorId
           FROM        FormCap fsg
           INNER JOIN  FlightTrip t
           ON          fsg.SourceId = '+convert(nvarchar(100),@reSourceID)+'
           AND         fsg.VendorId = '+convert(nvarchar(100),@VendorID)+'
           INNER JOIN  ContractProvider cpu 
           ON          t.Id = cpu.VendorId 
           WHERE      t.ID = '+convert(nvarchar(100),@FinTransID)+'
           AND       cpu.userID = '''+convert(nvarchar(100),@UserID)+''''

exec sp_executesql @statement
```

Comment: yea, I tried doing that, but @UserID is a UniqueIdentifier and the quotes tend to get a bit messy

Comment: Wrap them in repeated single quotes like my answer.  Should work fine.

Comment: I am still getting the same error ("Incorrect syntax near '@reSourceID'."). What would be wrong with the If statement?

Comment: The numeric fields need to be converted to string types when concatenating your string.  Ditto your UniqueIdentifier.

Comment: The error message still exists. Do I need a "Begin" & "End" between the If statements?

Answer (score 2):

As Bill answered, the optimim solution is probably going to involve dynamic SQL although I'd recommend going a little farther both for performance and security.

If you parameterize your call to sp_executeSQL you'll both avoid issues with escaping quotes and [potential SQL injection problems](http://xkcd.com/327/) but it will allow SQL to reuse the plan since the query text won't change.

Here's what that would look like:

```
if (@VendorID = 11)
    @reSourceID = 't.reSourceID'
if (@VendorID = 5)
    @reSourceID = 't.SourceID'

DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @params NVARCHAR(500)    

SET @sql ='SELECT t.ID, 
                  fsg.SigCap, 
                  fsg.VendorId
           FROM FormCap fsg
               INNER JOIN FlightTrip t
                   ON fsg.SourceId = '+CONVERT(NVARCHAR(MAX),@reSourceID)+'
                       AND fsg.VendorId = @VendorID
               INNER JOIN ContractProvider cpu 
                   ON t.Id = cpu.VendorId 
           WHERE t.ID = @FinTransID
               AND       cpu.userID = @userID'

SET @params = N'@VendorID INT, @FinTransID INT, @userID UNIQUEIDENTIFIER' 

EXECUTE sp_executesql @sql, @params, @venderID = @venderID, @finTransID=@finTransID, @userID = @userID
```

Above is the gist of the solution, I don't fully know your types and inputs. Also, without schema, I can't test my code, but it should get your going.

For more information on sp_executesql, [msnd is a great resource.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188001.aspx)

Comment: Just out of curiosity, if the code behind is parameterized when calling the stored proc, is it redundant to have parameterized query in the stored proc (for the intention of preventing SQL Injection)?

Comment: If you're concatenating strings and parameters, a SQL injection vulnerability is very likely. In your case there might not be one since you generate the only string and the rest are ints and uniqueidentifiers but it's still a good habit to have. Plus with a parameterized dynamic sql query, you get the added benefit of plan reuse.